# How to search for words in Amazon reviews?

Tags: amazon

I want to search for certain words/phrases in all book reviews on Amazon. Is there any way to achieve it?

Maybe something like: `inreview:layman`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the following Google search:

> [layman site:amazon.com/review](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=layman%20site%3aamazon.com/review)

Comment: Wow! That didn't struck to me at all!

Comment: Turns up many false results though........